# Laravel: Passing data to view through route after querying

Tags: laravel

I recently asked a question about defining many to many relationships (using belongsToMany) and it was a huge help. So now in my models I have:

**Users model**

```
 public function subjects()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject', 'users_subjects', 'user_id', 'subjects_id');
 }
```

**Subjects model**

```
  public function users()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'users_subjects', 'subject_id', 'user_id');
  }
```

This way I establish a relationship between `users` and `subjects` via the `users_subjects` table. My next step was to create a controller, SubjectsController, which ended up looking like this:

```
class SubjectsController extends Controller
{
  // returns the view where subjects will be displayed
  public function index()
  {
    return view('profiles.professor.prof_didactic_subjects');
  }

  // get users with subjects
  public function getSubjects()
  {
    $subjects = User::with('subjects')->get();
  }

  // get a single user with a subject
  public function getSubject($id)
  {
    $materia = User::where('id', '=', $id)->with('subjects')->first();
  }

}
```

I'm not very sure about the code in the controller though.

The final step is where it gets tricky for me, even after reading the docs: I want to pass each result to the view, so I can have multiple tiles, each populated with data from subjects the user is associated with:

```
@foreach ($subjects as $subject)
      <div class="tile is-parent">
        <article class="tile is-child box">
          <p class="title">{{ $subject['name'] }}</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>{{ $subject['description'] }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div> 
@endforeach
```

I tried many different route configurations, but kept getting either the undefined variable error or trying to access non-object error.

What's the proper course of action here? I feel I'm missing something very basic. Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**The answer**

The solution provided below by @Sohel0415 worked perfectly. My `index()` method on the controller now looks like this:

```
  public function index()
  {
    // temporary value while I figure out how to get the id of the current user
    $user_id = 6; 

    $subjects = Subject::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id){
      $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })->get();
    return view('profiles.professor.prof_didactic_subjects')->with('subjects', $subjects);
  }
```

My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/professor', 'SubjectsController@index');
```

I was pretty lost, so this absolutely saved me, thanks again :)

Comment: What is your blade/file name ?

Comment: @C2486 the blade file is called `prof_didactic_subjects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$subjects` to your `view`. You can use `compact()` method for that like -

```
public function index()
{
    $subjects = Subject::with('users')->get();
    return view('profiles.professor.prof_didactic_subjects', compact('subjects'));
}
```

Or using `with()` method like -

```
public function index()
{
    $subjects = Subject::with('users')->get();
    return view('profiles.professor.prof_didactic_subjects')->with('subjects', $subjects);
}
```

If you want to get `Subject` for a particular `user_id`, use `whereHas()` -

```
$subjects = Subject::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id){
      $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: @C2486 I guess it will give him enough idea how to pass data from controller to view

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Only one thing still confuses me: How can I retrieve only subjects the user is associated with in the `users_subjects` table? For example, if user_id = 6 is associated with subject_id = 2 and  subject_id = 3, how can I get only those two subjects?

Comment: @JulioKirk see my updated answer, you may have an idea, for better understanding see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Worked perfectly! Now it's just a matter of assigning to $user_id the value of the current authenticated user. I'll admit Eloquent and this part of the docs have been a bit hard for me, but I'll keep studying. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @JulioKirk welcome :) and you can see video tutorial at laracast too

Comment: I was saying about function `public function getSubjects()` and the code from view part `@foreach ($subjects as $subject)`.